# Does the target of Message know the caster's location?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, cantrips

Suppose someone casts Message while hiding from the target. Would anything be revealed about the caster's location?

Message ([Player's Handbook entry](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/message)) has a verbal component other than the message that is sent, so the target would know as much about the caster's location as they would with any other speech if they heard that part. (A related discussion on whether other characters can hear the message can be found [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/116594/can-people-other-than-the-target-hear-me-casting-message).)

However, suppose the target did not hear the initial casting of the spell. Would they know where the message came from? [I found this question about spells in general not revealing the caster's location in 3.5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24872/does-the-target-of-a-spell-know-who-is-casting-it), but I'm not sure if it applies to 5e or if Message would be different from other spells.

Comment: That question (which is the same one linked at the end of the 2nd paragraph) refers to the incantation used to cast the spell. However, for the sake of my question I am assuming that the target did not hear the initial casting.

Comment: Ah right. My bad! Misunderstood the question haha

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### No, being a target of *message* doesn't allow you to know caster's location

Nowhere in the description of *message* state that the target know your location, so they don't. If you chant the spell loud enough to reveal your location, then the target can deduce the general direction and relative distance you from them, if they hear that part.

Comment: If the recipient is familiar with the spell they could at least deduce how far away they must have been when it was cast.